# MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED stops working - How to find app upgrade android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdk-tools, target-sdk

I wanted to find the upgrade of my app. So i have been using this code to find it PACKAGE_REPLACED, but suddenly i could not receive event for package replacing of my app.

And i changed to MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED. still same issue.

Analysed some stack over flow questions. no luck. tried all of the answer.

My target sdk version is 30:

Manifest Code:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver" android:enabled="true" android:debuggable="true" android:exported="true"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver code

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.d(TAG, "action = " + action);

    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "BOOT COMPLETED, Ping start...");
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED.equals(action)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "PACKAGE REPLACED, upgrade ping...");
    } else {
        //default action is network changed
        Log.d(TAG, "network status changed...");
    }
}
```

Comment: " suddenly i could not receive event" - are you implying you had working code before?

Comment: @Pawel Sorry, Previously i was using this event  "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" where now it fails. i changed to MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED. but still failing to get the event.

Comment: I don't understand your sentence. Have this receiver ever worked or not?

Comment: yes. Action_PACKAGE_REPLACED was working but not now. @Pawel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering myself after analysing more stackoverlfow questions/answers and comments.

Previously, i was using **PACKAGE_REPLACED** event to receive the update and i have added package check as we receive this event for all package replaces.

But suddenly or i noticed now, app stops receiving the **PACKAGE_REPLACED** event.

And answers from stackoverflow says, we should use **MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED** .
which will not give any additional data.

Also, i have replaced it to **MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED** and tried by normal apk running from Android Studio. **This where i have made a mistake.**

Looks, we should run using the adb command, then only it triggers the package replace event

./adb install /Users/vijay/desktop/android/myapp.apk

The complete code:

manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=“.MPackageReplacedReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver code

```
class MyPackageReplacedReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
     override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
       Log.d(TAG, "package replaced event")
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your receiver, you should change this:

```
Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED.equals(action)
```

for this:

```
Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED.equals(action)
```

Comment: Sorry, that too not working.

Comment: Do you mean you have MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED in the manifest and the receiver but you still don't receive the event?

Comment: I have found my mistake and added as a answer above. Thanks for your reply.